# what does openerp-server do after I restart server with the para--update?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

What does openerp-server do after I restart server with the para--update?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you tend to use this in development along with a database parameter -d. This means that openerp will connect to the database and then update this module. Note that it is update only, it won't install. If other modules depend on the module being upgraded they will also be upgraded. You can also pass in a comma separated list of modules.

Comment: Could you give more details,please? Does this '--update' action only do some update to database?

Comment: It updates the module.  It is exactly the same as logging into the database, going to Settings -> Installed Module and then clicking the upgrade button on your module.  The option simply exists as an aid to developers so when you are working on the module it updates it everytime you restart OpenERP server